FluentAssertions: how to prepend each assertion failure message with custom text (parametrised)?
I have a simple task to accomplish, namely I need to prepend all assertion failures in a given unit test with a customised text containing some extra parameters of the tests.
Of course one good answer is to create a separate tests, each for a single variation of the unit tests mentioned above. The problem is that I have a relatively large set of parameter values [DataRow(...)] used for parametrised unit tests ([DataTestMethod]) which I don't want to duplicate.
Somebody mentioned that the AssertionScope can be used, however the string value being a parameter of the AssertionScope is used in a "hardcoded" way, disturbing the sense of the failure message.
Is there a way to include some extra data in the each assertion failure message using FluentAssertions (or maybe some other library allows it?)

Create one or more extension methods for the assertions, in which you customize the messages the way you want? ...

@RuiJarimba: Not really. I have a number of assertions and for each I would need to add the customised prefix. And this would need to be done for a large number of existing unit test methods.
